# How do I recover an overwritten file?

Tags: c, terminal, executable

I had a completely functional program that I accidentally just compiled as

```
gcc calendar.c -o calendar.c
```

instead of

```
gcc calendar.c -o calendar
```

which is horrid because the executable just overwrote my original code.  Is there any way I can undo this, or somehow reverse the executable to get my code back?  I just lost all of my work from a very stupid mistake and I'm trying not to panic.

I don't use Github or any other restoration program (which is something that I need to change immediately).

Help?

EDIT:  Looks like I'm out of luck.  The code is due at midnight tonight so it looks like it's marathon time for me.  I've certainly learned my lesson!  Thanks to everybody who commented :)

Comment: You don't need `Github` -- use `git`.  It's great!

Comment: What OS and filesystem?

Comment: Backups and source control systems. Won't help *now*, but things to remember for the future.

Comment: Yeah, it may be time to panic. If the file were deleted, you'd have a better chance at getting something back. The best you can hope for now is assembly. The question that @JohnZwinck asked is still relevant: what OS and fs is this on? Linux with ext3 seems likely.

Comment: There are tools, called decompilers, that turn a binary into *equivalent* code. But in the time it takes to turn the code it spits out into something similar enough to your original code, you may be able to write the code anew. Doubly so since the binary apparently lacks debugging symbols (i.e. all variable names will probably be lost).

Comment: In the future use make. Then your compile command is configured once and you don't run the risk of that sort of inadvertent error.

Comment: Ubuntu 13.10.  I don't know the difference between filesystems, but it's in a regular directory a few down from my home directory, if that helps at all.

Comment: @Worcestershire So are you using ext4 then?

Comment: @Worcestershire You can find out fs by running `mount`. Look for the mountpoint where your code lives under.

Comment: I would guess so?  I downloaded Linux last summer (dual boot) and I never changed the filesystem, so I suppose I have whatever the OS came with.

Comment: Now, you get maybe your first chance to experience/learn the fact that re-writing code from memory is way faster than writing it for the first place, even if you feel you don't remember it all.

Comment: Some editors (like joe) create a file if the editor was killed (DEADJOE), or make a backup (filename~) when the file was last edited.

Comment: I feel for you… **Don't panic though**, you wrote the program recently and it is still fresh in your memory and now you know what you are doing. It will go fast to reproduce the work you've done up until now. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the fact  you said you're using Ubuntu 13.10 and the files were in /home, you're about out of luck here.  Think about whether you might still have any editor open with the source code, or any program at all, because on typical *nix filesystems, when a file is removed its contents are still accessible to any program which has the file open from before.  Anyway I doubt that applies to you, and undelete utilities are not commonly used on "ext" filesystems like you are probably using (still, see this: http://extundelete.sourceforge.net/).

So learn a lesson, use source control, and perhaps even a real build system.

Sorry about that!